# SAS Visual Analytics report automating creation process

Tags: sas, sas-visual-analytics

Is there a way to automate the creation of a report in VA ?

I'm asking if it's possible to use a coding syntax to produce a report instead of doing it on the report builder page. I don't mind interacting with the metadata server on which resides Visual Analytics. I just need to create a report by coding instead of doing it visually.

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult, You will have to:

1. Reverse engineer the XML generated by an existing report object,
2. Write the XML of your own VA report,
3. Find a way to save the XML you generate to SAS Contents Server.